# Confused about understanding and silencing a -Wsign-compare gcc's warning

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, unsigned

Here is a function i am trying to compile :

```
static ssize_t  output(t_out_buffer *buf, char const *src, size_t size)
{
        size_t  osize;

        osize = size;
        while ((size > 0)
               && (size -= write(buf->fd, src, size) < osize))
        {
                src += osize - size;
                buf->count +=  osize - size;
                osize = size;
        }
        if (osize < size)
                return (T_OUT_BUFFER_ERROR);
        else
                return (buf->count);
}
```

And gcc's complain :

```
t_out_buffer.c:11:42: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    && (size -= write(buf->fd, src, size) < osize))
                                          ^
```

I assumed that as `size` is unsigned, `size -= whateverintiwant` would be unsigned as `osize` is unsigned too. I assume now that I was wrong but I do not really understand why.
Furthermore, can you give me hints to silence this ?

Comment: Of course this code will break disastrously should the `write()` ever return `-1`, so you need a rewrite anyhow.

Comment: if write returns -1, size will not just be incrementer by one ?

Comment: Yes, it will be incremented by one, and that is absolutely not what you want.

Comment: it is absolutely what i want ^^

Comment: Then may God have mercy on your soul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This expression isn't doing what you think:

```
(size -= write(buf->fd, src, size) < osize)
```

The less-than operator `<` has higher precedence than the compound assignment operator `-=`.  So the above parses as:

```
(size -= (write(buf->fd, src, size) < osize))
```

So this compares the output of `write` which is of type `ssize_t` with `osize` which is of type `size_t`.  This is where the signed/unsigned comparison happens.  The result of this comparison is then subtraced from `size`, so it will only ever decrease by 1 at a time.

Add parenthesis around the assignment:

```
((size -= write(buf->fd, src, size)) < osize)
```

And the warning will go away as you are now comparing a `size_t` with a `size_t`.

There's another problem however.  If `write` returns -1 then you'll be subtracting the value, i.e. adding 1, if it fails.

You should refactor so that you do the read inside the loop and only add the result if it succeeds.

```
    while (size > 0) {
    {
            ssize_t rval = write(buf->fd, src, size);
            if (rval == -1) {
                return T_OUT_BUFFER_ERROR;
            }
            size -= rval;
            src += rval;
            buf->count +=  rval;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your answer, I have been too slow! I am impressed you came with such a sophisticated answer in 6 minutes!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an operator precedence problem. Your code is interpreted:

```
&& (size -= (write(buf->fd, src, size) < osize)))
```

So, you can fix it by forcing the desired precedence:

```
&& ((size -= write(buf->fd, src, size)) < osize))
```

The warning is helping you by pointing out a problem, you should never silence a warning if you don't fully understand it.
Moreover, it is bad practice to use side effects inside a condition. Your code would be easier to understand and maintain if you moved the assignment operator `-=` outside the condition.

Comment: Ok, i'll move it out.

Comment: I am glad my answer wasn't completely useless :)